# Disabling a dropdown if a Textfield contains a certain value

Tags: javascript, html, input, conditional-statements

I have an issue with HTML and Javascript where I'm trying to create a condition that follows the following rules:

If the first text-box contains a certain word, disable the following drop-down.
If it doesn't contain that certain word, keep it enabled.

So far, I've got this code

```
var noSample = "HW8020";
const interval = setInterval(function() {
      // method to be executed;
      function codeCheck() {
        var x = document.getElementById("form-RequestAQuoteUK-9bbb_Products_Interest_Value").value;
      }
      function validateSample() {
      if ( x == noSample) {
        document.getElementById(
          "form-RequestAQuoteUK-9bbb_DropDown_Samples_SelectedValue"
        ).disabled = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById(
          "form-RequestAQuoteUK-9bbb_DropDown_Samples_SelectedValue"
        ).disabled = false;
      }
    }
}, 5000);
```

The noSample variable being the code that, when input into the text-field, will disable the dropdown. The Ids weren't my choice of naming, but I'm new to Javascript and am trying to fix an issue with the company I work for!

Any ideas?

Comment: Add a EventListener to your input (onKeyUp, OnChange, etc) when the event triggers check the value and act accordingly. Like a toggle function.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use event `input` instead of setInterval and use `indexOf` to check if `input.value` contains certain value.

```
var noSample = "HW8020";
let input = document.getElementById(
    "form-RequestAQuoteUK-9bbb_Products_Interest_Value",
);

input.addEventListener("input", () => {
    validateSample(input.value)
});

function validateSample(inputValue) {
    let selectEl = document.getElementById(
        "form-RequestAQuoteUK-9bbb_DropDown_Samples_SelectedValue",
    );
    if (inputValue.indexOf(noSample) > -1) {
        selectEl.disabled = true;
    } else {
        selectEl.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you can add an event listener to your **Products_Interest_Value** input and then enable or disable the dropdown based on whether or not this matches your `noSample` value.

```js
const noSample = "HW8020";

document.querySelector("#form-RequestAQuoteUK-9bbb_Products_Interest_Value").addEventListener("input", e => {
  document.querySelector("#form-RequestAQuoteUK-9bbb_DropDown_Samples_SelectedValue").disabled = (e.target.value == noSample);
});
```